# django url config passing multiple variables to views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

i am trying to pass multiple variable to a view via the url as bellow

```
url(r'stage/1/(?P<op>\w+)/(?P<id>\d+)$', 'HR.hr.views.stage_one_manage', name='view_stage_manage'),
```

the view is as follows

```
def stage_one_manage(request, op, id):
    print op, id
```

but when i visit /stage/1/ok/1 django is reporting a 404 is their a better way to capture the the op and id from the url ?

Comment: That's how it's done. Show more error.

Comment: The code is just fine. Check if this url is being found by django - in which directory is located? Is the app included in INSTALLED_APPS, etc..

Comment: @Tisho, I don't think you need to put the app in INSTALLED_APPS, it will work then also.

Comment: @nashr can you tell me this url regex you have written inside app or it is in projects urls.py because whatever you did is right, there is some url configuration problem.